# grab column elements from table header

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a table which has a search field. After searching data, the listed data are to be exported into excel which requires some extra information to be added which is not shown in the table, needs to be pulled from database.
So, I need to access all the listed data's id (after seraching). Also the  tag has no relevant 'id' or 'class' so that it can be grabbed, since it were rendered using datatables. How can this be achieved using jquery

## code snippet

```
<table id='mytable' border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th id='ID'>ID</th>
        <th id='Email'>Email</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>abc@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>xyz@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>pqr@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button id='gen'>Generate excel file</button>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xLA3g/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at this, may it helps
http://jsfiddle.net/xLA3g/3/

```
$('#mytable tr th').each(function(i){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

**ANSWER UPDATE**, show td column number
http://jsfiddle.net/xLA3g/4/

```
$('#mytable tr td:first-child').each(function(i){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

let me know if I can help assist any further

Comment: thanks....This just showed the table headers only. I am trying to extract ID like 1,2,3 for this example

Comment: I've posted the complete solution in jsfiddle for others..      
http://jsfiddle.net/keJBZ/3/

Comment: is there something like second-child, the id seems to be in the 2nd column unfortunately..

Answer (score 1):

Modify a little @carambas answer

```
var ids=[];
$('#mytable tr th').each(function(i){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    ids.push($(this).attr('id'));

});
console.log("ID",ids);
```